# Table formatting issue in Overleaf

Tags: tables, formatting, color, longtable, overleaf

I am using Overleaf for a report and my table header isn't formatting correctly. This is the initial part of the code (the table is long, spanning across two pages - it has 20 rows.

I am a total beginner so I can't figure out what is going wrong here. The red color is not properly reflecting in the last two columns. Help please! It's a small issue but its annoying. 
[image]

```
\begin{center}
\label{table:2}

\begin{longtable}{ | m{1.5cm} | m{2cm} | c | c | c | c  | c | c | }

\multicolumn{8}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

\caption{Status and national electrification plans and achievements in five selected African countries (Source: MEI)}

  \hline \hline
  \rowcolor{redmei} \color{white}
  Country & \color{white} Electrification Plans & \color{white} \thead{Total Offgrid \\ Population \\ (million)} & \color{white} \thead{Electrification \\ Rate} & \color{white} \thead{Rural \\ Electrification \\ Rate} & \color{white} \thead{Urban \\ Electrification \\ Rate} & \color{white} \thead{Power \\ Outages \\ (duration \\-hours)} & \color{white} \thead{Power \\ Outages \\ (frequency\\-month)}  \\ 
  \hline
    \cellcolor{redmei} \color{white} 
    Uganda & 26\% coverage by 2022; 51\% coverage by 2030 & 32.1 & 22\% & 10\% & 55\% & 6 & 6.3 \\
  \hline
    \cellcolor{redmei} \color{white} 
    Kenya& 65\% coverage by 2022; universal by 2030& 35.4 & 20\% & 7\% & 60\% & 6 & 6.3 \\
  \hline    
    \cellcolor{redmei} \color{white} 
    Rwanda & 70\% of HH connected by 2018, 100\% by 2020 & 9.3  & 21\%  & 5\%   & 67\% & 4 & 4 \\
.
.
.
.
   \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Could you please  make your code compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages? With the information you have provided so far, the error is not reproducible. Also, please note that `longtable`s are horizontally centered by default, so no need for the `center` environment.

Comment: Additionally, a `\\ ` is missing just after the `\caption` command. Lastly, your `\label` command is at the wrong position. It should be placed immediately after the `\caption` command in order to allow `\ref` to print the correct counter. You might also want to consider replacing `\color{white} 
    Uganda` by `\textcolor{white}{Uganda}` as the former command changes the textcolor for the following cells as well, so your text in white background and the table lines get invisible.

Comment: you should not put `longtable` in a center environment, also `\label` would not normally do anything useful in a `center` but perhaps it is labelling some heading that you have not shown. Please always provide a complete document that shows the issue.

Comment: @leandriis it is not just that the `center`  environment is not needed, it does not center it and it adds spurious vertical space, so it is wrong not just unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the clarification. My wording was definitely imprecise.

Answer (score 2):

If  I correct the errors that were already mentioned in the comments, I can't reproduce your issue:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\definecolor{redmei}{RGB}{192,0,0}
\begin{document}

%

\begin{longtable}{ | l | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm} | c | c | c | c  | c | c | }

\multicolumn{8}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

\caption{Status and national electrification plans and achievements in five selected African countries (Source: MEI)}\label{table:2}\\

  \hline \hline
  \rowcolor{redmei} \textcolor{white}{Country} & \textcolor{white}{ Electrification Plans} & \textcolor{white}{ \thead{Total Offgrid \\ Population \\ (million)}} & \textcolor{white}{ \thead{Electrification \\ Rate}} & \textcolor{white}{ \thead{Rural \\ Electrification \\ Rate}} & \textcolor{white}{ \thead{Urban \\ Electrification \\ Rate}} & \textcolor{white}{ \thead{Power \\ Outages \\ (duration \\-hours)}} & \textcolor{white}{ \thead{Power \\ Outages \\ (frequency\\-month)}}  \\ 
  \hline
    \cellcolor{redmei} \textcolor{white}{Uganda} & 26\% coverage by 2022; 51\% coverage by 2030 & 32.1 & 22\% & 10\% & 55\% & 6 & 6.3 \\
  \hline
    \cellcolor{redmei} \textcolor{white}{Kenya} & 65\% coverage by 2022; universal by 2030& 35.4 & 20\% & 7\% & 60\% & 6 & 6.3 \\
  \hline    
    \cellcolor{redmei} \textcolor{white}{Rwanda} & 70\% of HH connected by 2018, 100\% by 2020 & 9.3  & 21\%  & 5\%   & 67\% & 4 & 4 \\

   \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```